# Multilanguage Support Cordova App

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

Hello I want to make my cordova mobile app as multilanguage.
I have two js file {lang.en.js and lang.tr.js} in resource folder.
in files there is a string object below for languages.

```
var strings = {
    app_name: "Capser",
    facebook_login_btn: "Login with Facebook",
    gmail_login_btn: "Login with Gmail"
}
```

Now I want to choose languge depends on mobile language. I installed globalization plugin and wrote function below.

```
function setLanguage() {
    if (typeof (localStorage.language) === 'undefined') {
        if (typeof (navigator.globalization) !== 'undefined') {
            navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(function (language) {
                if (language.value.indexOf('en') != -1)
                    localStorage.language = 'en';                
                else
                    localStorage.language = 'tr';
            }, function () {
                localStorage.language = 'tr';
            }
            );
        }
        else if (typeof (navigator.language) !== 'undefined') {
            var language = navigator.language;

            if (language.indexOf('en') != -1)
                localStorage.language = 'en';           
            else
                localStorage.language = 'tr';
        }
        else {
            localStorage.language = 'tr';
        }
    }
}
```

in index.js firstly I call this function then i choose js file.

```
setLanguage();
var languageScript = 'resources/lang.' + localStorage.language + '.js';
```

My problem starts here. I want to reach this string object from file.

```
$.getJSON(languageScript, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

I wrote above, but not working. How can I get datas from js file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As your target file is not a JSON, you shouldn't use `getJSON` method. But if you want to import this language file, and assuming in that files the only thing you have is language translations, it could be an option to make that files pure JSON, and import them using `$.getJSON` as described, and it should work. For instance, lang.en.js should be just:

```
{
   app_name: "Capser",
   facebook_login_btn: "Login with Facebook",
   gmail_login_btn: "Login with Gmail"
}
```

And then you can load this file with jQuery using `$.getJSON` and, in its callback, you should get translation data.